# Stale Requests on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, ios-simulator

I am getting stale requests for all my web-service calls when running on iOS simulator, however running on a device runs perfectly fine

I've compared the calls themselves using Charles, and they are getting made exactly the same

This is only happening in one particular computer, I've tried running on simulator on other PC's and they also run fine, using the exact same project settings, through an SVN checkout

I've tried deleting derived data in Xcode, doing a clean, reset content and settings, uninstalling/re-installing Xcode... even creating a new account on the PC and installing a fresh copy of Xcode there, but the problem persists..

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried calling this: `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]removeAllCachedResponses];` ? I had similar issues before with this. Our problems may be different though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, just tried it, but the problem is persisting...

Answer (score 0):

Really old, but it might help someone... I had manually changed the time on my computer, so the time that was sent in the request from the simulator being received by the server mismatched, causing these stale requests apparently... (re-checking set date and time automatically, fixed this issue)